# permissions for list views

Tags: list-view

i have a custom list, and was wondering if it is possible to set permissions on list views? users can view all of the data, but i'm trying to limit which views they can see. For example, I have two views(District, Region), which only supervisors should be able to view. this is to minimize confusion.

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight to answering your question - ***it's imposible to set permissios on list views*** to secure data. You can only set permissions on list folders and items.

But if you just want to personilize records in list you can use [**Target Audience**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/target-content-to-specific-audiences-HA010169053.aspx) - views will display only record set for some target audience, but other items still can be accessed via their url, so it can't be used in security.

Hope it'll help.

Comment: I think using audiences will be the way to go. Most of the users are not very technical, so I'm trying to present only the information that is relevant to them.